# how to insert data into phpmyadmin table using bootstrap form

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

**how to insert data to phpmyadmin using save button in modal**

> what can code can i use for, so that i can insert data to phpmyadmin coming from the bootstrap modal. very thankful for those who will answer my question.

[here is the picture of my phpmyadmin tbl_books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5saFA.png)

```js
<?php
 $server = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $pw = "";
 $db = "b1_bm";

 $conn = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pw);
 
 if(!$conn) {
  die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  
 }
 
 mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

 


 
?>
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td{
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
 background-color: #primary;
}

th{
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}

#btnsubmit{
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 border: 0px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#txtsearch{
 height: 20px;
 width: 190px;
}


#form-search{
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 1070px;
}

#btnAddBook{
 position: absolute;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <link href = "css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <form id="form-search" action = " main.php" method = "post"> 
  <input id="txtsearch" type = "text" name= "search" placeholder ="Enter keyword here..."/>
  <input id="btnsubmit" type = "submit" name= "submit" value= "Go"/>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <div class = "table">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <th>ISBN</th>
     <th>Book Title</th>
     <th>Book Author</th>
     <th>Genre</th>
     <th>Year Published</th>
     <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
   <?php 
    include('connection.php');
    
    
    
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    
    $sql = "Select * from tbl_books where isbn like '$search'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   
    echo "<tr>
       <td> ". $row['isbn'] ."</td>
       <td> ". $row['title'] ."</td>
       <td> ". $row['author'] ."</td>
       <td> ". $row['genre'] ."</td>
       <td> ". $row['year_published'] ."</td>
       <td> ". $row['description'] ."</td>
   
    </tr>";
    
     }
    } else {
    $sql = "Select * from tbl_books";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   
    echo "<tr>
     <td> ". $row['isbn'] ."</td>
     <td> ". $row['title'] ."</td>
     <td> ". $row['author'] ."</td>
     <td> ". $row['genre'] ."</td>
     <td> ". $row['year_published'] ."</td>
     <td> ". $row['description'] ."</td>
   
    </tr>";
    
    }
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
   ?> 
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class = "container">
  <button id = "btnAddBook" type = "button" class = "btn btn-success" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#myModal">Add Book</button>
 <div class = "modal fade" id = "myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class = "modal-dialog">
   <div class = "modal-content">
    <div class = "modal-header">
     <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
     <h4 class = "modal-title">Add Book</h4>
    </div>
    <div class = "modal-body">
     <form role = "form">
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "exampleInputIsbn">ISBN</label>
       <input name = "isbn" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter ISBN">
      </div>
      
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "exampleInputTitle">TITLE</label>
       <input name = "title" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter the title of the book">
      </div>
      
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "exampleInputAuthor">AUTHOR</label>
       <input name = "author" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter the author of the book">
      </div>
      
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "exampleInputGenre">GENRE</label>
       <input name = "genre" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter the genre">
      </div>
      
      <div class = "form-group">
       <label for = "exampleInputYearPublished">YEAR PUBLISHED</label>
       <input name = "year" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Year published">
      </div>
      
      <div class = "form-group" method = "post">
       <label for = "exampleInputDescription">DESCRIPTION</label>
       <input name = "description" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Description">
      </div>
     </form>
     
    </div>
    <div class = "modal-footer">
     <button name ="save" type = "button" class = "btn btn-success" data-dismiss = "modal">Save</button>

     
    </div>
     
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  
    
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple post form, this was just made so you get an understanding of how inserting values into mySQL databases using post forms.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link href = "css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

<form id="form-search" action = " main.php" method = "post"> 
<input id="txtsearch" type = "text" name= "search" placeholder ="Enter keyword here..."/>
<input id="btnsubmit" type = "submit" name= "submit" value= "Go"/>
</form>
<hr>
<br>
<div class = "table">
<table>
<tr>
  <th>ISBN</th>
  <th>Book Title</th>
  <th>Book Author</th>
  <th>Genre</th>
  <th>Year Published</th>
  <th>Description</th>
</tr>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
include('connection.php');

$sql = "Select * from tbl_books where isbn like '$search'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr>
<td> ". $row['isbn'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['title'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['author'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['genre'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['year_published'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['description'] ."</td>

</tr>";

}
} else {
$sql = "Select * from tbl_books";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr>
<td> ". $row['isbn'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['title'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['author'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['genre'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['year_published'] ."</td>
<td> ". $row['description'] ."</td>

</tr>";

}
}

?> 
</table>
</div>
<div class = "container">

<form method="post">
<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "exampleInputIsbn">ISBN</label>
<input name = "isbn" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter ISBN">
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "exampleInputTitle">TITLE</label>
<input name = "title" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter the title of the book">
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "exampleInputAuthor">AUTHOR</label>
<input name = "author" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter the author of the book">
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "exampleInputGenre">GENRE</label>
<input name = "genre" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter the genre">
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "exampleInputYearPublished">YEAR PUBLISHED</label>
<input name = "year_published" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Year published">
</div>

<div class = "form-group" method = "post">
<label for = "exampleInputDescription">DESCRIPTION</label>
<input name = "description" type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Description">
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['isbn']) && !empty($_POST['isbn'])) {
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$year_published = $_POST['year_published'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

$insert = ("INSERT INTO tbl_books(isbn, title, author, genre, year_published, description) 
  VALUES ($isbn, $title, $author, $genre, $year_published, $description)");
}
$result = mysql_query($insert, $conn);

?>      

</body>
```